# Conectarse a servidor FTP por Filezilla en Red Local Inalambria (wifi)

Tags: windows, servidor, ftp, filezilla

Bueno el punto es que baje filezilla server en mi pc:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al cual con filezilla Cliente puedo acceder facilmente desde mi pc:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y de la web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al intentar con otro pc conectado al mismo router o LAN,
no puedo ni desde la web ni con filezilla client:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la confuguracion de filezilla server lo tenia en default en la parte de "Configuracion de modo pasivo", ahora lo cambie  a esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no veo que funciones tampoco a menos que este cometiendo algun error al conectarme.

por favor alguien podría decirme como lograr eso.tengo entendido que no debería ser difícil ya que no es un servidor publico.Gracias.

Comment: Tendrías que usar la ip de tu ordenador en vez de la del localhost, la puedes ver con ipconfig.

Comment: Lo intente, en el otro pc puse " ftp:// 192.168.1.42" que es la ipv4 de mi pc

Comment: Revisa la configuración de filezilla Servet. Creo recordar que x defecto no admite conexiones externas a la IP del propio servidor

Comment: lo configure ahora como la imagen que agregue a la pregunta.

Comment: Verifica tu firewall, de ser necesario debes crear la regla que permita desde tu LAN el acceso a los puertos del servidor FTP

Comment: abri el puerto 21. en reglas de entrada y salida. nose si basta. al otro pc le hice una regla de entrada del puerto 21 tambien. auque ahora como cambie la configuracion nose que mas deberia hacer.

Comment: deberías deshabilitar el firewall y el antivirus temporalmente para ver si es por eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En respuesta a mi pregunta, resulta que al final probe con otro "router", internet compartido desde un celular , y solo tuve que usar filezilla con su configuracion predeterminada y funciono perfectamente usando la ipv4, entonces el router seria el problema en este caso.